# Convert PHP entities like &ndash; or &scaron; to their applicable characters

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, tinymce

is there a way how to convert HTML entities to their applicable characters. Something similar to **html_entity_decode()**?
I'm trying to make ordinary text without HTML entities from TinyMCE output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [user contributed notes](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#78665) in the manual, `html_entity_decode()` seems indeed to convert only some 100 entities instead of the over 200 that exist in the spec.

There's a script named `html_entity_decode_full` that seems to provide decoding for all entities, but the original author's site is down. [Here](http://drupal.org/files/issues/mail-decode-full-entities.patch)'s a link to a Drupal repository that contains the function. This will convert all entities:

```
/* Test call */
echo decode_entities_full("&ndash; THIS IS A DASH", ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8");

/**
 * Helper function for drupal_html_to_text().
 *
 * Calls helper function for HTML 4 entity decoding.
 * Per: http://www.lazycat.org/software/html_entity_decode_full.phps
 */
function decode_entities_full($string, $quotes = ENT_COMPAT, $charset = 'ISO-8859-1') {
  return html_entity_decode(preg_replace_callback('/&([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+);/', 'convert_entity', $string), $quotes, $charset); 
}

/**
 * Helper function for decode_entities_full().
 *
 * This contains the full HTML 4 Recommendation listing of entities, so the default to discard  
 * entities not in the table is generally good. Pass false to the second argument to return 
 * the faulty entity unmodified, if you're ill or something.
 * Per: http://www.lazycat.org/software/html_entity_decode_full.phps
 */
function convert_entity($matches, $destroy = true) {
  static $table = array('quot' => '&#34;','amp' => '&#38;','lt' => '&#60;','gt' => '&#62;','OElig' => '&#338;','oelig' => '&#339;','Scaron' => '&#352;','scaron' => '&#353;','Yuml' => '&#376;','circ' => '&#710;','tilde' => '&#732;','ensp' => '&#8194;','emsp' => '&#8195;','thinsp' => '&#8201;','zwnj' => '&#8204;','zwj' => '&#8205;','lrm' => '&#8206;','rlm' => '&#8207;','ndash' => '&#8211;','mdash' => '&#8212;','lsquo' => '&#8216;','rsquo' => '&#8217;','sbquo' => '&#8218;','ldquo' => '&#8220;','rdquo' => '&#8221;','bdquo' => '&#8222;','dagger' => '&#8224;','Dagger' => '&#8225;','permil' => '&#8240;','lsaquo' => '&#8249;','rsaquo' => '&#8250;','euro' => '&#8364;','fnof' => '&#402;','Alpha' => '&#913;','Beta' => '&#914;','Gamma' => '&#915;','Delta' => '&#916;','Epsilon' => '&#917;','Zeta' => '&#918;','Eta' => '&#919;','Theta' => '&#920;','Iota' => '&#921;','Kappa' => '&#922;','Lambda' => '&#923;','Mu' => '&#924;','Nu' => '&#925;','Xi' => '&#926;','Omicron' => '&#927;','Pi' => '&#928;','Rho' => '&#929;','Sigma' => '&#931;','Tau' => '&#932;','Upsilon' => '&#933;','Phi' => '&#934;','Chi' => '&#935;','Psi' => '&#936;','Omega' => '&#937;','alpha' => '&#945;','beta' => '&#946;','gamma' => '&#947;','delta' => '&#948;','epsilon' => '&#949;','zeta' => '&#950;','eta' => '&#951;','theta' => '&#952;','iota' => '&#953;','kappa' => '&#954;','lambda' => '&#955;','mu' => '&#956;','nu' => '&#957;','xi' => '&#958;','omicron' => '&#959;','pi' => '&#960;','rho' => '&#961;','sigmaf' => '&#962;','sigma' => '&#963;','tau' => '&#964;','upsilon' => '&#965;','phi' => '&#966;','chi' => '&#967;','psi' => '&#968;','omega' => '&#969;','thetasym' => '&#977;','upsih' => '&#978;','piv' => '&#982;','bull' => '&#8226;','hellip' => '&#8230;','prime' => '&#8242;','Prime' => '&#8243;','oline' => '&#8254;','frasl' => '&#8260;','weierp' => '&#8472;','image' => '&#8465;','real' => '&#8476;','trade' => '&#8482;','alefsym' => '&#8501;','larr' => '&#8592;','uarr' => '&#8593;','rarr' => '&#8594;','darr' => '&#8595;','harr' => '&#8596;','crarr' => '&#8629;','lArr' => '&#8656;','uArr' => '&#8657;','rArr' => '&#8658;','dArr' => '&#8659;','hArr' => '&#8660;','forall' => '&#8704;','part' => '&#8706;','exist' => '&#8707;','empty' => '&#8709;','nabla' => '&#8711;','isin' => '&#8712;','notin' => '&#8713;','ni' => '&#8715;','prod' => '&#8719;','sum' => '&#8721;','minus' => '&#8722;','lowast' => '&#8727;','radic' => '&#8730;','prop' => '&#8733;','infin' => '&#8734;','ang' => '&#8736;','and' => '&#8743;','or' => '&#8744;','cap' => '&#8745;','cup' => '&#8746;','int' => '&#8747;','there4' => '&#8756;','sim' => '&#8764;','cong' => '&#8773;','asymp' => '&#8776;','ne' => '&#8800;','equiv' => '&#8801;','le' => '&#8804;','ge' => '&#8805;','sub' => '&#8834;','sup' => '&#8835;','nsub' => '&#8836;','sube' => '&#8838;','supe' => '&#8839;','oplus' => '&#8853;','otimes' => '&#8855;','perp' => '&#8869;','sdot' => '&#8901;','lceil' => '&#8968;','rceil' => '&#8969;','lfloor' => '&#8970;','rfloor' => '&#8971;','lang' => '&#9001;','rang' => '&#9002;','loz' => '&#9674;','spades' => '&#9824;','clubs' => '&#9827;','hearts' => '&#9829;','diams' => '&#9830;','nbsp' => '&#160;','iexcl' => '&#161;','cent' => '&#162;','pound' => '&#163;','curren' => '&#164;','yen' => '&#165;','brvbar' => '&#166;','sect' => '&#167;','uml' => '&#168;','copy' => '&#169;','ordf' => '&#170;','laquo' => '&#171;','not' => '&#172;','shy' => '&#173;','reg' => '&#174;','macr' => '&#175;','deg' => '&#176;','plusmn' => '&#177;','sup2' => '&#178;','sup3' => '&#179;','acute' => '&#180;','micro' => '&#181;','para' => '&#182;','middot' => '&#183;','cedil' => '&#184;','sup1' => '&#185;','ordm' => '&#186;','raquo' => '&#187;','frac14' => '&#188;','frac12' => '&#189;','frac34' => '&#190;','iquest' => '&#191;','Agrave' => '&#192;','Aacute' => '&#193;','Acirc' => '&#194;','Atilde' => '&#195;','Auml' => '&#196;','Aring' => '&#197;','AElig' => '&#198;','Ccedil' => '&#199;','Egrave' => '&#200;','Eacute' => '&#201;','Ecirc' => '&#202;','Euml' => '&#203;','Igrave' => '&#204;','Iacute' => '&#205;','Icirc' => '&#206;','Iuml' => '&#207;','ETH' => '&#208;','Ntilde' => '&#209;','Ograve' => '&#210;','Oacute' => '&#211;','Ocirc' => '&#212;','Otilde' => '&#213;','Ouml' => '&#214;','times' => '&#215;','Oslash' => '&#216;','Ugrave' => '&#217;','Uacute' => '&#218;','Ucirc' => '&#219;','Uuml' => '&#220;','Yacute' => '&#221;','THORN' => '&#222;','szlig' => '&#223;','agrave' => '&#224;','aacute' => '&#225;','acirc' => '&#226;','atilde' => '&#227;','auml' => '&#228;','aring' => '&#229;','aelig' => '&#230;','ccedil' => '&#231;','egrave' => '&#232;','eacute' => '&#233;','ecirc' => '&#234;','euml' => '&#235;','igrave' => '&#236;','iacute' => '&#237;','icirc' => '&#238;','iuml' => '&#239;','eth' => '&#240;','ntilde' => '&#241;','ograve' => '&#242;','oacute' => '&#243;','ocirc' => '&#244;','otilde' => '&#245;','ouml' => '&#246;','divide' => '&#247;','oslash' => '&#248;','ugrave' => '&#249;','uacute' => '&#250;','ucirc' => '&#251;','uuml' => '&#252;','yacute' => '&#253;','thorn' => '&#254;','yuml' => '&#255;'
                       );
  if (isset($table[$matches[1]])) return $table[$matches[1]];
  // else 
  return $destroy ? '' : $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Or simply you can use:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#38;', ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 4):

I originally wrote [the code that's pasted into Pekka's answer](http://inanimatt.com/php-convert-entities.php) - it's nearly completely unnecessary except in specific cases (mostly for removing non-existent entities, which `html_entity_decode()` doesn't touch, or for converting to numeric entities if you're making XML that isn't UTF-8 encoded).

TinyMCE has an option to return raw (not HTML-encoded) output, so that should be your first point of call. Look at this [entry in the TinyMCE manual](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aentity_encoding) for more info on that.